# How to distinguish MacBook and Mac desktops programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm working on a Mac app that should distinguish MacBook and Mac desktops (iMac/Mac Pro).

I think I can get it done with model number. Then how I can get the model number? And which letter indicates it's a notebook or desktop? Or is there any other easier or better way?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but one application that might help you research the answer is [MacTracker](http://mactracker.ca/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this little program. `NSLog` the output to test it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

+ (NSString *)machineModel
{
    size_t length = 0;
    sysctlbyname("hw.model", NULL, &length, NULL, 0);      
    if (length) {
        char *m = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
        sysctlbyname("hw.model", m, &length, NULL, 0);
        NSString *model = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:m];
        free(m);
        return model;
    }
    return @"Unknown model";
}
```

It will provide the same output as entering `sysctl hw.model` on the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't specified a language, but from Terminal `sysctl hw.model` will return with an identifier for the current Mac. For example, on my computer it returns `MacBookPro5,5`.

Comment: Nice one. I added an answer that uses this command from objective-c code.