# Cocoa: How to identify if it is a Desktop or Laptop by obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am showing battery left time in my application using the given below code:

```
-(int)getLeftTimeMinutes{

    CFMutableDictionaryRef matching , properties = NULL;
    io_registry_entry_t entry = 0;
    matching = IOServiceMatching( "IOPMPowerSource" );
    entry = IOServiceGetMatchingService( kIOMasterPortDefault , matching );
    IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties( entry , &properties , NULL , 0 );

    NSDictionary* arr = CFBridgingRelease(properties);

    NSNumber *AvgTimeToEmpty =  [arr objectForKey:@"TimeRemaining"];

    if (AvgTimeToEmpty == nil) {
        return 0;
    }

    return [AvgTimeToEmpty integerValue];    
}
```

**Problem**

In case, if user is using a desktop then I need to show a message that you are directly connected to AC power.

How do I find out that the user has a desktop?

**My Research**

[StackOver Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518501/how-to-distinguish-macbook-and-mac-desktops-programmatically): Here if found a similar question but the solution they are providing is to get the model number of the system. If I use this method then I will need to keep updating the model numbers so that my code does not break with is not practical.

Please suggest what should I do...

Many thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [IOPSGetTimeRemainingEstimate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPSGetTimeRemainingEstimate) function, which returns `kIOPSTimeRemainingUnlimited` if attached to an unlimited power source. Don't forget, mac book still may be connected to AC power too.

Comment: is there a way to get how much system is charged and how much is left?? @astoria

Comment: @VikasBansal I think your should deal with `IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo`-function. Try to look at the dictionary contents it returns.